# Test $H_0 : \beta_i =\alpha \times i$ for a model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, anova

Consider the model $Y_{ij} = \beta_i + \epsilon_{ij}$ for all $i=1,2,...,k$ and $j=1,2,...,n_i$,

$\epsilon_{ij} \sim \text{i.i.d} \  N(0, \sigma^2)$.

How can I test $H_0 : \beta_i = \alpha \times i\ $ for all $i=1,2,...,k \ \ $ v/s $\ H_1 :$ not $H_0$.

I think we need an F-statistic to test this, and it might be given by $\frac{\frac{SSE(H_0)-SSE}{k}}{\frac{SSE}{n-k}} \sim F_{k,n-k}$. But I am not being able to find $SSE(H_0)$.

Comment: Is $\beta_i=i\alpha$ in the model or only under $H_0$? If it's the latter, then $\alpha$ must be known.

Comment: I think you are correct, it should be known under $H_0$.

Comment: So this is a special case of testing $H_0: \boldsymbol\beta=\boldsymbol\beta_0$ where $\boldsymbol\beta_0$ is any specified vector.